# Match at least one element in sequence of optional elements (ANTLR)

Tags: antlr, antlr4, grammar, boolean-logic

Let's consider the following ANTLR4 grammar (minimal example):

```
grammar Foo;

expr
   : a? b? c?
   ;
```

How could I specify that **at least one** of `a`, `b`, or `c` must be present in `expr`?

Basically I'm looking for a shorter version of the following:

```
grammar Foo;

expr
   : a
   | b
   | c
   | a b
   | a b c
   | b c
   | c
   ;
```

Is there a simpler way to achieve this directly in the grammar, or do I need to check the AST after parsing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not as simple as the hypothetical "at least one of" operator, but simpler than the solution you propose would be:

```
expr
   : a b? c?
   | b c?
   | c
   ;
```

At least, it is `n` productions for `n` things, instead of `2n−1` productions.